# How to get value from SQL Select in VB using ADO

Tags: vb6, ado

I try to get value from SQL Select but it returns 0. This is a code

```
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo vbError

SetStoredProcedureValues RS, "pro_GetCustomerCount", DTMConn

 With dbComm
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@CompanyID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 5, strCompanyID)
    Set RS = .Execute
End With


If Not RS.EOF Then
    intAA = RS!intA
    intBB = RS!intB
End If

''cleanup
DestroyRS RS

Exit Function
```

This is the procedure

```
DECLARE @intA INT, @intB INT    
SELECT @intA = COUNT(txtNo) FROM tblCompany_Customer WHERE txtCompany = 'x' GROUP BY txtNo
SELECT @intB = COUNT(txtNo) FROM tblCompany_Customer1 WHERE txtCompany = 'x' GROUP BY txtNo

SELECT ISNULL(@intA, 0) AS intA, ISNULL(@intB, 0) AS intB
```

This is SetStoredProcedureValues

```
Public Function SetStoredProcedureValues(rsSP As ADODB.Recordset, strSP As String, Conn As ADODB.Connection)

Set dbComm = New ADODB.Command
Set dbParam = New ADODB.Parameter
Set rsSP = New ADODB.Recordset

With dbComm
    .ActiveConnection = Conn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = strSP
    .CommandTimeout = 0
End With

End Function
```

When I run the procedure pro_GetCustomerCount, that returns two values:

intA: 55

intB: 55

When I retrieve value from the procedure in VB via 
RS!intA or RS!intB, they return 0.

I don't know why it happens. Any suggest is appreciated

Comment: as you are getting values I would suggest the query you are running is not what you think. Why is 1_SP_GetCustomerCount different to pro_GetCustomerCount?

Comment: Hi Rob, I just edit and have mistake, may you refresh page again?

Comment: can you show the whole stored procedure and SetStoredProcedureValues

Comment: Change the stored procedure so that includes the line "SET NOCOUNT ON"

Comment: @GMastros would that make a difference here? Presumably they are closed recordsets

Comment: @Rob I cannot be sure.  If I was, I would have posted as an answer instead of a comment.  I am reasonably sure it will work, but not 100% confident.

Comment: Hi @Rob, I edit post and add function you required

Comment: and the full text for pro_GetCustomerCount?